# Windows Phone 8 emulator error - Hyper-V missing

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

In my Windows Phone app,I am facing an error when try to run the `emulator`. Error comes with following description:
[image]

BTW I am using `windows 8.1` which is `not activated` yet! How to fix this error ?

Comment: Is it a 64bit Pro version?

Comment: Is Hyper-V installed? Go to "Turn Windows features on or off" and make sure the "Hyper-V" box is checked.

Comment: no its not installed ! @GerritFölster
i am on it !

Comment: its 64bit ! not showing which version ! @igrali

Comment: If it doesn't say Pro in the System properties, then it probably isn't Pro. In order to install Hyper-V: "Client Hyper-V requires a 64-bit system with second level address translation (SLAT) capabilities and additional 2 GB of RAM (Windows 8.1 Pro only)"

Comment: is there anything else rather than changing my OS  ??? @igrali

Comment: Sorry, I think there is no other option.

Comment: On machines without Hyper-V available/installed, your only debugging option is to deploy/test with an actual physical device.