# I cannot run windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfDod.png

Dear Experts,

I am a newbie to windows phone development and when running the project on VS2012, I get this error message (as shown in the link above)and I am not able to resolve it. Trying playing around with the settings on BIOS without any result.

Please assist me. Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Mohammed Mohsen

Comment: Is Hyper-V installed? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936489/windows-phone-8-emulator-error-hyper-v-missing

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if Hyper V is supported by your hardware ? you can read [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/does-your-pc-have-what-it-takes-to-run-windows-8s-hyper-v/4254) to get an idea about how to check, that might be the cause

Comment: If you are running Windows 7 the update in this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/why-am-i-receiving-errors-about-hav) might solve your problem